# Live Installation USB won't boot to 21:9 Ultrawide Monitor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, monitor

Stats:

- LG 34" 3440x1440 monitor (connected via HDMI)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 16.10 (tried both)
- Intel NUC Skull Canyon NUC6i7KYK
- UEFI enabled (tried it with it disabled too)
- Fastboot disabled
- Secureboot disabled
- Windows 10 already installed (and partition shrunk)

What happens:

I plug in the live USB and start the computer. I select the USB device after pressing F10. I select 'install Ubuntu' in the following menu. I see a weirdly pixelated Ubuntu-colored keyboard at the bottom. I see a console with a blank and then a couple lines. Then, everything goes blank, and my monitor goes to sleep because it has no input.

What's going on?

- Does Ubuntu not read 3440x1440 without some customizing after you've already installed it?
- Is there a step I'm missing?
- If this is Ubuntu's fault, would this problem go away if I installed Ubuntu on another device, updated everything, and then brought it back to my monitor?
- Could it be anything hardware-related? NUCs aren't pre-built systems, so I wonder if something needs to be set correctly, but then again I've already used Windows with it)
- If there's nothing that I can do about this, do you recommend any other Linux distros?

Edit: My work around was using DisplayPort to connect to the monitor instead of HDMI. I have no idea why the HDMI connection wouldn't work. Dualbooting Windows, the HDMI cable worked fine with the same PC and same monitor.

Comment: Did you get 16.10 to boot? I can only get 16.04.1 to boot on my skull canyon. I've got a Dell U2715H 2560x1440 monitor on miniDP.

Comment: try after turning on an option `legacy boot` in the bios...